# Set value for a selected cell in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm selecting the data I want to change not by its index but by some criteria. And the DataFrame contains many user's number, but one user has many information with different time. Now I want to select the same user's information,and then order one's data according by time. For my purpose, I want to replace the NAN with a number.

[image]

So,as you can see in the picture, d'nan is filled by number 2,but df'nan don't change.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import copy
from datetime import datetime
df=pd.DataFrame({'User':[1,2,3,4,3,5],'Income':[5,6,np.NAN,8,9,np.NAN],
    'Time':[datetime(2001,1,1),datetime(2001,1,2),datetime(2001,1,3),                            datetime(2001,1,4),datetime(2001,1,5),datetime(2001,1,6)]},
           columns=['User','Time','Income'])
d=df[df['User']==3].sort_values(by='Time').copy()
for index in d.index:
    if pd.isnull(d.ix[index]).any():
        d.loc[index,'Income']=2
print(d)
df
```

Comment: are you after `df.Income.fillna(2, inplace=True)`?

Comment: Please post your code as text, so those willing to help could copy and paste it

Comment: I have afterd ```df.Income.fillna(2, inplace=True)```,but don't have any change in result. By the way, I have pasted my code  above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [58]: df
Out[58]:
   User       Time  Income
0     1 2001-01-01     5.0
1     2 2001-01-02     6.0
2     3 2001-01-03     NaN
3     4 2001-01-04     8.0
4     3 2001-01-05     9.0
5     5 2001-01-06     NaN

In [59]: df.Income.fillna(2, inplace=True)

In [60]: df
Out[60]:
   User       Time  Income
0     1 2001-01-01     5.0
1     2 2001-01-02     6.0
2     3 2001-01-03     2.0
3     4 2001-01-04     8.0
4     3 2001-01-05     9.0
5     5 2001-01-06     2.0
```

Comment: I know you can operate df is OK.But my quesiton is that I can't operate df directly.Because for different user, there is different value for Nan, and the data ,df, is very large.

Comment: I have found the problem.Do you know the following code why different.

Comment: ```import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import copy
d=pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,1,2],'b':[6,4,6]})
d=d.sort_values(by='b',inplace=False)
# c=d[d['a']==1].copy()  # 
# c.loc[1,'a']=11  # why d[1,'a'] not change
# d

c=d[:]
c.loc[1,'a']=11  # why d[1,'a'] not change
d

Comment: ```import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import copy
d=pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,1,2],'b':[6,4,6]})
d=d.sort_values(by='b',inplace=False)
# c=d[d['a']==1].copy()  # 
# c.loc[1,'a']=11  # why d[1,'a'] not change
# d

c=d[:]
c.loc[1,'a']=11  # why d[1,'a'] not change
d ```

Comment: I am sorry I am not familiar with stackoverflow. This is my first time to log in.Any way ,thank you very much

Comment: @han1219, it's not changed because you used `.copy()` which duplicated your cells. What are you trying achive?